# How to differentiate between words with the similar letters?

Tags: word-usage

I am not a native , so it is hard for me to find out the difference between the words with similar letters.

e.g.

1. **substitute :** use or add in place of.
2. **substantiate :** provide evidence to support or prove the truth of.
3. **substantial :** of considerable importance, size, or worth.
4. **substance :** a particular kind of matter with uniform properties.

what I really see is "word start with subs and include Ts and As".

Is there a better way to learn this kind of words ?

Comment: What is the real question? It's not very clear. Could you elaborate?

Comment: In my native language , I know there are a tricky ways to memorize and remember such words in such context in such situation. for me it is hard to memorize and remember this kind of words.

Comment: You need to understand the meaning of the endings of these Latinate words.  -ute, iate, ial, ance.  They occur over and over again in English.

Answer (score 2):

The trick of learning anything, be it language, or anything, is to ***associate*** the words with an object, or a sentence. These kinds of questions are generally off-topic here, but this may help you.

When somebody says *'substitute'* to me, the first thing that comes to my mind is a game of football. You substitute a player. Or I remember a classroom, a substitute teacher. That way, I'll never forget what substitute means. Use examples.

Similarly, associate these words with examples, sentences and objects. Initially that method maybe slow, but once it sets in, you will not have a problem.

If you say substance to me, I recall the terms '*chemical substance*'. Now I'll not forget what it means. Similarly, use associations to help you learn.